# MongoDB Aggregate pipeline with $group and $count on a Pointer reference returns wrong data

Tags: database, mongodb, parse-platform, aggregation-framework, parse-server

I have a set of data in MongoDB with *parse-server* in the following format-

```
 Rating => objectId, user<_User>, rating...
 _User => objectId, gender<m|f|nb|na>
```

I have been trying to group the data based on the user's gender to find out how many male, female, non-binary or N/A users have rated. **user** field in a pointer reference to **_User**. I am using the following aggregate pipeline.

```
const pipeline = [
      {
        lookup: {
          from: '_User',
          localField: 'user',
          foreignField: 'objectId',
          as: 'user'
        }
      },
      {
        unwind: { path: '$user' }
      },
      {
        group: {
          objectId: '$user.gender',
          count: {
            $sum: 1
          }
        }
      }
    ]
const data = await new Query('Rating').aggregate(pipeline)
```

Result =>

```
[
        {
            "count": 54,
            "objectId": "na"
        },
        {
            "count": 405,
            "objectId": null
        },
        {
            "count": 27,
            "objectId": "f"
        },
        {
            "count": 540,
            "objectId": "m"
        }
    ],
```

However, returned data count doesn't match with actual data. ***The actual database has only 27 ratings with 1 f, 2 na, 24 m.***

For MongoDB developers, *objectId* is equavalent to *_id*.

I am a novice to aggregation framework. What am I doing wrong?

*Server Environment-*
parse-server: 3.2.3
mongodb: 4.0.2

Comment: Try this: `{"$unwind":{ "path": "$user", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true }},`

Comment: @Valijon it's still the same

Comment: Can u post some input data to try in my local? Can you group `_User` and `Rating` collections just to discard wrong information

Comment: @AshrafulAlam : Is your user field in rating collection an Array ? - seems like an array as you're doing unwind on user. If so then it might be the cause as you unwind, it will explode the rating documents with repeated users, Ex: {RatingDoc1 - userA},{RatingDoc1 - userB},{RatingDoc2 - userA},{RatingDoc2 - userB},{RatingDoc2 - userC}..finally group will blindly get count of each gender looking into each document of exploded Rating's user.gender field..!! If it's not the case please provide sample documents to look into issue..

Comment: @srinivasy it's a parse pointer object `{ __type: "Pointer", className: "_User", objectId: "OAUEuTLv9Q"}`

Comment: @Valijon rating object looks like this-
`{
            "objectId": "bWWDJZfrDP",
            "business": {
                "__type": "Pointer",
                "className": "Business",
                "objectId": "12B7aTXBbF"
            },
            "user": {
                "__type": "Pointer",
                "className": "_User",
                "objectId": "OAUEuTLv9Q"
            },
            "rating": 5,
            "comment": "Some comment text here",
            "createdAt": "2019-02-15T17:32:53.939Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-02-15T17:32:53.939Z"
        }`

Comment: @AshrafulAlam : Can you do "user.objectId" in localField of your query, I haven't seen something like this before.. :-)

Comment: @srinivasy, it returns same result with *"user.objectId"*. The object on top is mongo equivalent to - `{ "_id" : "bWWDJZfrDP", "_p_business" : "Business$12B7aTXBbF", "_p_user" : "_User$OAUEuTLv9Q", "rating" : 5, "comment" : "Some comment text here", "_created_at" : ISODate("2019-02-15T17:32:53.939Z"), "_updated_at" : ISODate("2019-02-15T17:32:53.939Z") }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is tricky because you need to understand how Parse Server stores the data inside the MongoDB. The following query should solve your problem:

```js
  const query = new Parse.Query('Rating');

  const pipeline = [
    {
      project: {
        objectId: 1,
        userId: { $substr: ['$_p_user', '_User$'.length, -1] }
      }
    },
    {
      lookup: {
        from: '_User',
        localField: 'userId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'user'
      }
    },
    {
      unwind: { path: '$user' }
    },
    {
      group: {
        objectId: '$user.gender',
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }
  ];

  return await query.aggregate(pipeline, { useMasterKey: true });
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!